# Can I conditionally avoid hitting a trigger completely?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

We had to use a trigger to sync an old system to the new system until we can fully deprecate the old system.  The new system doesn't need this trigger at all and, in fact, exits out immediately on the condition that it's the new app.

The impact on the old system is acceptable.

However, the impact on the new system is not because the new system processes many, many more records on a single update.  Merely executing the trigger changes an update from 10 seconds (already "UGH") to over a minute and a half.

The new system performs acceptably by disabling the trigger in code (VS Core with EntityFramework btw), running the update and then re-enabling the code, all within a transaction.  There is disagreement among my colleagues about whether or not the trigger is disabled for the other application while the transaction is being processed.

I have already seen this post:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204339/sql-server-how-to-disable-trigger-for-an-update-only-for-your-current-session

And the first answer is the solution I am using.  My colleagues tell me that won't work.  I believe it will.  But the answers 2-whatever seem to contradict the first answer.

My testing proved out the first answer as well but I need to be 100% sure on this.

TIA

Comment: As long as a trigger is present in SQL Server and enabled, it **will fire** - there's no trick or "backdoor" into making it avoid being fired. The **only way** is to explicitly disable (or drop) it before your operatoin.

Comment: Ok thanks.  But do you concur that DISABLE TRIGGER within a transaction eliminates the possibility of other users updating while the trigger is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

> However, the impact on the new system is not because the new system processes many, many more records on a single update.

You should find a way to batch the updates into fewer statements.  The trigger fires per statement, not per row.  EG EF Core does batching automatically, or you can use a TVP or SqlBulkCopy into a temp table, etc.

> DISABLE TRIGGER within a transaction eliminates the possibility of other users updating while the trigger is disabled

Yes. You can easily verify that disabling the trigger takes a Sch-M lock on the table for the duration of the transaction, which is incompatible with all other table access.

eg

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists t


create table t(id int primary key)

go
create trigger t_t on t after insert 
as
begin
  select 'trigger running' msg
end

go

begin transaction

go
disable trigger t_t on t 
go

select  object_name(resource_associated_entity_id) table_name, resource_lock_partition, request_mode, request_status 
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where request_session_id = @@spid 
and resource_type = 'OBJECT'
order by 1,2

rollback
```